# Save forms to SharePoint: Fieldnames vs Displaynames

Tags: cognito-forms, sharepoint

Is there any way to save data to the **displayname** of a SharePoint list field, instead of the **internal fieldname**? SharePoint has a habit of changing internal fieldnames, which means that the labels on my Cognito Forms would have to adapt to these fieldnames, in order for the data to show up in a SharePoint list.

Obviously, this is not desired if you want to offer your customers a registration form...

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/) responsible for the SharePoint integration features.

We do think that this feature would be a great addition to our system and have added this to our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/Zt1YggsE). Feel free to follow our progress on this feature over on our Idea Board or submit other feature requests through our [Request a Feature](https://www.cognitoforms.com/featurerequest/) form. We try to keep our members updated to new features we are releasing with a newsletter that is sent out before each release.